# CodeIgniter Session getting destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have two codeigniter applications running on a single server, sharing same database.
They have been configured with db session driver storing individual sessions in different tables

> for eg: for app1 it is Table ci_session_app1 and app2 it is Table
>   ci_session_app2

config for app1

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions_app1';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

config for app2

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions_app2';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I am trying to login in both the apps on same browser window, the problem that occurs is when i sign in app1, and proceed to signing in on app2, a successful app2 login logs' out the user from app1. The vice versa also stands true.

Also, When i logout from one of the apps ( app1 for instance ), the other app (app2) also results a logout for the user.

I read a few articles on internet about CI session issues with too many Ajax requests, but i doubt mine is a similar case to that. Can someone give any pointers ?

My CI version is 3.1.5 ( as seen in CodeIgniter.php file from Core )

Answer (score 0):

just set separate **encryption_key** per app in config file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'app_enc_key';
```

Comment: Tried this just now does not work. app1 has `$config['encryption_key'] = 'ABCDEF123456';`

and app2 has `$config['encryption_key'] = '123456789';`

Comment: what is sess_cookie_name in both app?

Comment: i have commented that setting as i am using database to store sessions